# Oracle: best way to deal with NULL values

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have this piece of code within a procedure:

```
 if val is NULL
    then 
    creb :=0;
   else 
     creb := val;
 end if;
```

Is there more elegant way to deal with null?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `coalesce ()`, which returns the first non-null value in the list if values passed to it:

```
creb := coalesce(val, 0);
```

Answer (score 5):

As a complement to Bohemian's answer, Oracle has the non-standard [`NVL`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm) -- and the [`NVL2`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2049.htm#OLADM625) if you need an *else* case with a value different from the condition -- functions to deal with that issue.

```
creb := nvl(val, 0);
```

[`COALESCE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617) has both advantages of being standard and accepting multiple arguments.